# Is it possible to do a call-cc in Go?

Tags: go, callcc

Is it possible to do a [Call-with-current-continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation) in Google's new Language [Go](http://golang.org/)?

Comment: Which use do you want an equiv for?  For yielding, or for coroutines, or?

Comment: Can we `give Go a rest`, and/or seek Go-related info `at the source`, until the language has a broader community of effective practitioners?

Comment: Replace **go-language** with **go**, which seems to have won (and makes more sense)

Comment: call/cc! What a feature! IMHO `call/cc` is to gorotines/closures as `goto` is to `for`/function calls. see [Call/CC considered harmful](http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/against-callcc.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to one of the go contributors, [no](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/acc8d4c20d050d6a/dd3ff3417873672) it's not possible.

Comment: Good call.  Two points from that thread: (i) go closures are heap allocated (not trampolined or anything), and (ii) "Goroutines are equivalent to one-shot (use and forget) continuations".